# Continue indices instead of starting over in Python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a problem to which I have had a hard time finding a solution to.

I need to read multiple tab separated documents. One of the columns in each document contain a sentence-word index on the form(1-1, 1-2,...,1-11, 2-1...) etc. For my task I need to combine multiple documents into a list for a NLP task. This is no problem. However, this means that when there is a new document in the list, the sentence index starts over from (1-1), naturally. I wish to write a function that continues to count the sentences, disregarding that it is a new document.

That is, instead of for example (61-10, 61-11, 1-1, 1-2...), I wish to have (61-10, 61-11, 62-1, 62-2...) and so on. The word index is not that important, so a solution which only has the sentence index is perfectly fine!(i.e (61, 61, 62, 62,...).

So far, I have tried a solution where I isolate the sentence index in a list as shown below, but I do not know how to continue. `df` is a panda df.

```
sentence = []
for i, ind in enumerate(df["Sectionindex"]):
    sent = re.search('(.+?)-\d+', ind)
    sentence.append(int(sent.group(1)))
```

Hope that my question is clear enough, I am relatively new to python.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean `df.reset_index()`, this will of course will start from 1 and countinue, so if you read you multiple documents into one df, you will be able to `.reset_index()` I´m not sure if I get the question.

Comment: Maybe it was unclear calling it an index per se, it is more of a variable that is indexing the sentences in each document. That is, the variable has nothing to do with the row index in the list/df, it only relates to the original documents and their contents.

Comment: so you whant to control wich document the content come from and set a index/identifer related to content = document?

Comment: I want to have a "global" sentence-index, that continues the index on the next document where the previous documents last sentence-index ended. Lets say that Document 1 has 63 sentences and hence has 63 has its last sentence-index. Then I want the first sentence in Document 2 to have sentence-index 64.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a global index as you said, start at 0, increment by whatever sentence-index you reached in this document?

```
sentence = []
global_sentence_index = 0
for i, ind in enumerate(df["Sectionindex"]):
    sent = re.search('(.+?)-\d+', ind)
    global_sentence_index += int(sent.group(1))
    sentence.append(global_sentence_index)
```